# Forcing Interface Builder to change class of objects(UIButton->UIControl)

Tags: interface-builder, uibutton, uicontrol, inspector

I have a UIView filled with buttons that are all nicely hooked up to actions and outlets. However, in my infinite wisdom, I decided that I really would rather have the button behavior to be different and subclassed a UIControl.

My plan was to hop into Interface Builder, change the class of the buttons to my new UIControl subclass, and then be up and running.  This would preserve all of outlet and action connections.

In IB (View Identity Inspector) when I type in my UIControl subclass into the class field, it reverts back to UIButton when I tab out.  Any UIButton subclass works, but not a UIControl. I can go down the inheritance tree but not up....

The first plan was to go to XCode and change the superclass of my new control temporarily to UIButton, change the 'class' of my IB buttons, and then change the XCode code superclass back to UIControl.  IB accepted and changed the class, but running the app gives me non-visible buttons. The IB Attributes inspector still shows it as a button.

Creating the control from scratch and rewiring works, but I was hoping to not rewire all the buttons if it could be avoided.  (This is a change I was hoping to roll across multiple apps, so it is a bit more painful that it sounds)

Anyone know any way around this?

many thanks!

Comment: forgot my basics. This is happening on XCode/IB 3.2.3

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a year late on this, but maybe it will help someone in the future. Perhaps you could open the .xib in a text editor and figure out what text you would have to change to get it to work (try it on a sample project first), then use find and replace to fix all of them at once.